# Is dew and water vapour the same?

Tags: phase, vapor-pressure

Is it possible to say water vapour and dew is the same? I know that the water vapour is the gaseous phase of water. But what is the dew? I just wonder how can I categorised it. Is it the liquid  or the gas phase of the water.

Figure below shows dew formed in grass. It seems as a liquid. But is it actually  exhibit in liquid phase or gas phase?

[image]

Comment: @  santiago : Why the question falls to "off-topic" when I ask for opinions?

Comment: @Onthewaytosuccess 'primarily opinion based' is a close reason, the information states `Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.` - but, as I mentioned, it is now on topic and has great answers.

Comment: Why would you think it's not a liquid?

Answer (score 5):

Let's have a look at the definitions of dew:

> **dew** ([the free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dew))
>
> 1. Water droplets condensed from the air, usually at night, onto cool surfaces.
> 2. Something moist, fresh, pure, or renewing: "The timely dew of sleep / ... inclines / Our eye-lids" (John Milton).
> 3. Moisture, as in the form of tears or perspiration, that appears in small drops.

Therefore dew is water in the condensed phase, i.e. liquid. Water vapour on the other hand is the gaseous phase. They are definitely not the same.

Comment: Then what is the connection between water  vapour and dew?

Comment: Water changes its state of aggregation from gaseous (vapour) to liquid (drops, dew), that process is called condensation.

Comment: Can I take it as latent heat of vapourization?

Comment: @Onthewaytosuccess I don't understand this question.

Comment: I mean the heat  produce in the process that you just mention above as   latent heat of vapourization?

Comment: Can I take it like that?, I means as  latent heat of vapourization.

Comment: @Onthewaytosuccess It might be better if you asked this as a new question, currently, I really do not understand what you are trying to learn. Is it about the terminology? Do you want to know what latent heat is?

Comment: Yes ,is it a serious one?

Comment: @Onthewaytosuccess I really do not understand what you mean with that either. If you want to talk about any of that, please come to the chat and we might find a way to resolve that...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25060/discussion-between-on-the-way-to-success-and-martin-).

Answer (score 2):

As dew is condensed water vapour [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dew) and condensation is the change of matter from gas phase to liquid phase [[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensation) dew is clearly liquid water.

So on the one hand they are somehow the same as they both consist of water but on the other hand they are not the same as they are water in different states of matter.